# Telegram API integration in java add user to supergroup via api

Tags: java, playframework, telegram

I'm trying to integrate my application with Telegram (web and mobile). the objective is simple and as follows -

1. To ensure user is part of a public supergroup (in which my bot is
   added as admin with all permissions),
2. if he is not part of the group, provide him a button (with invitation link) to join the group
3. Upon clicking the button let him 'join' the group. Ideal way is to be able to use some API method like `joinUserToGroup(user_id, chat_id)`, but I know that's not feasible.

All methods of bot api work fine for me - I'm able to check if the user is a member of the super group and generate invite link. However, when user clicks on the link (on web), and if he is not logged into the web.telegram.org, he cannot join the group (only button shown to user is with tg:// namespace link which doesn't work on web)

Is there a working example somewhere that you can help me with? My stack is Java + play framework 2.4.6, + Mysql.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the way it works with Telegram has its restrictions.